# openpyxl add maximum value label to line chart

Tags: python, openpyxl

How can I add a label to the maximum value in a chart via openpyxl. I'm only able to show all labels or the first one but not the nth one. Please advise? Thanks

Comment: You can set the data label for individual members of a series.